# How to find duplicates by row in excel

Tags: excel, find, duplicates, row

I've been looking for a way to see which rows have duplicate words in.

If a word matches in column A and C I would like to add a "X" to column B. The whole cell shouldn't have to be exactly the same for example, John Miller and Miller,J This needs to only match words in the same row and not the entire column. I have 50k plus rows to work through so I'm looking for a better way,any help would really be appreciated

Here's what it looks like:

```
A


Jf Wepener . Lourens Johannes Stephanus

Me Horn x Horn Maria Elizabeth

Jg Waldeck x Waldeck Johan George

Pj Du Preez x Preez Paulus Jacobus Du
```

Comment: Ahw thank you its pretty close but it still doesn't put "X"s in certain places like Zb Mathenjwa : Mathenjwa Ziphozethu Busisiwe 
Tnx a lot though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Excel you have long formula (To work well). Following the scheme:

[image]

First Split the String Column A for searcing. In the colums:

```
D: =TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(A2;SEARCH(" ";A2;1));A2))
E: =TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(MID(A2;LEN(D2)+2;99);SEARCH(" ";MID(A2;LEN(D2)+2;99);1));MID(A2;LEN(D2)+2;99)))
F: =TRIM(IFERROR(LEFT(MID(A2;LEN(D2)+LEN(E2)+3;99);SEARCH(" ";MID(A2;LEN(D2)+LEN(E2)+3;99);1));MID(A2;LEN(D2)+LEN(E2)+3;99)))
```

in the column B:

```
=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2;C2));IF(D2="";FALSE;TRUE));AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2;C2));IF(E2="";FALSE;TRUE));AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2;C2));IF(F2="";FALSE;TRUE)));"x";"")
```

In this way you can have space (at the end) or not. If you have more words in the column A you shall add formula.
It's Better / You can split and HIDE the columns no necessary for generate the results...

Comment: Tnx I got the column split but for some reason I can't the =IF part to work

Comment: Thats what I did :) I mean I can't get this part working :=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2;C2));IF(D2="";FALSE;TRUE));AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2;C2));IF(E2="";FALSE;TRUE));AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2;C2));IF(F2="";FALSE;TRUE)));"x";"")

Comment: Thank you so much that was it works great I really owe you one :)